# Google Autocomplete cannot resolve getActivity()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new in android programming and I have this snippet from somewhere in the internet and it says "cannot resolve getActivity()" I then tried to use getApplicationContext() but the Autocomplete did not function. What should I do to get it running without problems?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Button btnFindPath;
//private EditText etOrigin;
//private EditText etDestination;
private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    AutoCompleteTextView etOriginView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
    etOriginView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.autocomplete_list_item));
    etOriginView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                            // Get data associated with the specified position
                                            // in the list (AdapterView)
                                            String description = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });

    btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
    //etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
    //etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);

    btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendRequest();
        }
    });
}
```

PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter Class

```
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

ArrayList<String> resultList;

Context mContext;
int mResource;

PlaceAPI mPlaceAPI = new PlaceAPI();

public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);

    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Last item will be the footer
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return resultList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                resultList = mPlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    return filter;

}
```

}

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
My Google Places API Web Service tells me that I have 100% errors, so does it mean that something is wrong with my Adapter?

Comment: That's what you get when you copy paste without understanding each line of code. You're already inside an `Activity` so calling `getActivity()` makes no sense. How about `this` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try **MapsActivity.this** insted of **getActivity()**